# Random 500 Internal server error from ajax request

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, apache

I got a random error from my server.
**It is not happening always** so it is not a parameters or wrong URL issues.

The parameters and the URL are the same in each request.
No reference in the server logs.

On the server side I have few "for" loops and 2 db "selects" so maybe the mySql failed or the server???

It is a Godaddy hosting.

Need an advice... I'm attaching few images for example.

[image: the Firefox net console]

[image: response]

EDIT:
Sorry guys I would added the ajax.php file but there is no problem with it.
Just look that I wrote that It happens in a randomly way.
Same parameters, same url, same DB, same functions...

I'm attaching new image... I wrote Loop in js that is checking every 5 seconds if the ajax is still running, if yes abort it and shoot another one.
What happens now is that there are 5-10 ajax until I got an answer from the server (the answer is about 500ms)

Maybe the server is the problem? How can I check it?
Thanks!

Comment: click on one of the error lines to see if there is any repsonse text.

Comment: We will need to have a look at `ajax.php` to suggest you something

Comment: victory look at the last image... I attached file of it.

Comment: I had the same issue about random ```500``` errors when updating a json and then loading it in a second ajax request. I solved it by triggering the second ajax request after the first one is done (the first one changes the json, the second one loads it from another place inside the html).

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
 error_reporting(E_ALL); 
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

inside Ajax.php, that will tell the php to output errors rather than just getting an 500 internal server error from the web server

That way you get to see what causes the error

Comment: This could have been a comment as it's just about debugging

Comment: @asprin yes, but as the op did not post any code, this is as about as constructive an answer as can be expected

Comment: @asprin is sat error_reporting(E_ALL); and ini_set('display_errors', 1); but no error appear

Comment: @llioor as stated, you might wanna check your server logs. There will be something listed there.

Answer (score 1):

`500` indicates an `Internal Server Error`, i.e., an error that happened server-side.
You should debug `ajax.php` and see what is causing it to terminate. Looking at your `error_log` file often helps, too.